# Bootstrap- Carousel doesn't work at all

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

[Visual Studio Community 2015] I have linked the Bootstrap fonts, CSS, and JavaScript (along with a few other custom ones for styling and testing functions). I have tried this generic block of code in another HTML file, and it works (via Bootstrap). But for some reason, when the "arrows" are clicked in my other HTML file, it will just move me down the page.

Carousel Code
'

```
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>'
```

Full HTML

```css
.navbar {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            background-color: steelblue;
            z-index: 9999;
            border: 0;
            font-size: 12px !important;
            line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
            letter-spacing: 4px;
            border-radius: 0;
            font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
        }

            .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
                color: #fff !important;
            }

        .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
            color: steelblue !important;
            background-color: #fff !important;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
            border-color: transparent;
            color: #fff !important;
        }

        footer .glyphicon {
            font-size: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            color: steelblue;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="A website about the ___ App Studio, my life, and where I test a bunch of cool stuff!">
    <meta name="author" content="Name">
    <title id="title">Bootstrap | JavaScript Test</title>
    <!--Stylesheets (Bootstrap v3.5.5)-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="../CSS/BodyForm.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Logo</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#blog">BLOG</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container body-content">        

        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="..." alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="..." alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
                ...
            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>


        <div class="row">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <p class="text-center " id="padjust">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                    <p id="contact" class="text-center">Non-adjustable text. Should be centered tho. Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="panel-footer">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <select id="font" class="form-control">
                <option value="12">Size 12</option>
                <option value="14">Size 14</option>
                <option value="18">Size 18</option>
                <option value="24">Size 24</option>
                <option value="36">Size 36</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <input type="button" onclick="setFont()" value="Change font" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </footer>
    <!--JavaScript Custom and Bootstrap v3.5.5-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../JavaScript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../JavaScript/Testing.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The above HTMl would of course be using Bootstrap, but it won't slide left or right.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across the same problem after reorganizing my html document. I solved it by putting this Bootstrap JavaScript CDN script into the body instead of the head.

```
<body>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Hope this helps fix your probelm.